# Firebase callable cloud functions security & CORS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to implement a callable cloud function into my firebase application which would store secrets to a secret manager bucket.

I understand that the callable function has access to the auth.uid from the session once a user loggs in and that I can implement the validation within the function but I would still like to know how to secure the public endpoint of the function because I can see that if I simply try to visit the function URL it actually counts towards the cloud invocation quota even though it returns an error.

I tried disabling the allUsers invocation permission within the function settings and that actually makes the url inaccessible but at the same time i get this error when trying to call the function from my app -

Access to fetch at 'https://europe-west1-atlaspark-app.cloudfunctions.net/{cloudFunctionName}' from origin 'https://atlaspark-app.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any suggestion to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [**Firebase HTTPS Callable Functions**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which has a feature of **Firebase Authentication** to authenticate users to your app.

But you want to make your Cloud Function private in order to be secure and not accessed publicly.

=======**EDIT**=======

- **Why your URL is not accessible after making your Cloud Function private?**

  Since the Cloud Function is private, it needs Authentication to be accessed. You will not be able to access the Cloud Function endpoint from the browser since it needs the Authorization token related to the IAM user or service account who has the permissions to invoke the Cloud Function. And the browser is not providing an authorization token automatically.

- **You are getting the CORS issue on the client side.**

  I have reproduced the issue by creating a **private Cloud Function** ( by removing the `AllUsers` Member from the `Cloud Function Invoker Role`) and calling it from a Firebase app. And I indeed was getting the CORS issue.

In order to avoid CORS, I tried to add the Cloud function as a **Firebase Hosting** rewrite in firebase.jon :

**Note: [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only so this option will not be a solution for you. However I did the following test with Firebase Hosting in us-central1**

```
"rewrites": [

{
"source":"/test",
"function":"test"
}
]
```

Also, I changed the Cloud functions code to verify [ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)

**Cloud function**

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require(".ServiceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL"
});

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   cors(req, res, () => {
   const tokenId = req.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1];

   return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId)
      .then((decoded) => res.status(200).send(decoded))
      .catch(function(err) {
           console.error(err);
           console.log(err);
           res.status(401).send(err)});
      });
});
```

**Client Side**:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
.then(function(idToken){
    console.log('Id token is..');
    console.log(idToken);

    fetch('Cloud_Function_endpoint',{
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify({ data })
    }).then(result => {
       console.log(result);
    }).catch(error => {
       console.log(error);
   });
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

So after making these changes, I was no longer getting the CORS issue however I was getting the 401 `(Unauthorized)` error.

### Solutions Tested:

- We can’t use **Firebase Hosting**, as there is no Firebase Hosting service account to add roles/permissions since requests are originated from clients.
- To secure a Cloud Function, an alternative is to enable the [Domain Restriction Sharing Policy (DRS)](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-domains) and this way we will not be able to serve public Cloud Functions.
- But the previous is the same as removing the `AllUsers` from a Cloud Function making it private.
- I was able to find that for the private functions, we can specify an IAM policy for a given user / service account. And to authenticate the requests from the client, we will need to supply a bearer token associated with [the user / service account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).But this also can’t be achieved since the bearer token required for IAM is too short lived to be used in **firebase.json** file.

### Conclusions:

- It is not possible to access a private Cloud Function from a Firebase app.
- The only solution is to have a public Cloud Function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but as i mentioned in the post im actually getting this error with the  Firebase HTTPS Callable Function when i delete the allUsers Invoker permission in my IAM settings thus trying to have the function http trigger endpoint only accessible for users of my app.

Comment: Oh I see, could you please share your code in order to see what could be causing these errors?  I Will update the answer afterward.

Comment: So for example a basic test function : 

`const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.test = functions
  .region("europe-west2")
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    try {
      return { success: true };
    } catch (e) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError("unknown");
    }
  });`

Which i then call in my frontend component with :
`firebase.app().functions('europe-west2').httpsCallable('test')`

Comment: The CORS error in console with callable functions only indicates there is an error in the Cloud Function. Could you please check the logs inside the Firebase console and see the actual error ? CORS is not applicable for callable functions as they are added automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. The function only throws this error when i go to IAM and revoke allUsers function invoker permission for the given function. If i reapply this role to IAM the function works again.

Comment: Have you given the user access to your Cloud Function URL by giving the Cloud Function
 Invoker Role? Please check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#serving) explaining the error

Comment: I provided the invoker permissions to the <appname>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com which is the default app engine service account for the application but the error persists. Shouldn't this be the account which needs invoker permissions to access the function from within my application?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks I was suspecting that this would be the conclusion but your answer really laid it out in a comprehensible way. I am a bit concerned that this creates a loophole for spam or DDoS attacks to rack up invocation costs and as far as my research goes Google does not offer supreme protection for these types of attacks. People mention that the protection tier kicks in when the costs would already be in the 'cloud' (pun intented). Is there a known way to mitigate this except billing notifications and invocation quota limits?

Comment: I understand your concerns.  You can leave your Cloud Functions public but enforce operations using auth or use [API gateway](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-functions) with Firebase auth but calling the function with an HTTP request

Comment: @NibrassH Thanks for mentioning that Firebase hosting rewrites only works for **us-central1** region functions. I was deploying my Express.js API function to three different regions thinking it will reduce latency for different users across the globe.